# ParseRelyingPartyInputClaimsAsync is not supported for Web.TPEngine.Providers.SamlProtocolProvider

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have configured Azure AD B2C custom policy to support SAML accordingly to the steps presented in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

Unfortunately when I am trying to open the policy page to sign in, there is an error page displayed. I managed to get more details from the Azure AD B2C backend. This is the error I get:

*ParseRelyingPartyInputClaimsAsync is not supported for Web.TPEngine.Providers.SamlProtocolProvider*

Did someone face similar issue in the past? I see that is it probably related to input claims however I cannot find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the root cause. The error message is very misleading.

The problem was related to the **objectId** claim and its mapping.

In the relying party technical profile, objectId should be declared as output claim along with the **SubjectNamingInfo** element added. Here is the full profile:

```
<RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignInSignUp" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="SAML2" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mobileNumber" PartnerClaimType="phone_number" />     
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="aud"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent" ExcludeAsClaim="true"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
```

Then I was able to successfully display the login page.